# My IP changes after reboot

Tags: dhcp, ip

I have Ubuntu server 20.04 and it got IP from DHCP. The LAN Team define my IP and mac in DHCP to reserve IP for me, but every time after reboot my IP got changed.
we can't fix IP manually in our company. do you have any idea?

Comment: Is your network device changing its MAC address automatically? If so, that can be disabled via Network Manager.

Comment: no, my mac address is always the same. just ip address is changing

Comment: This seems like an issue that your LAN Team needs to know about. Whatever they did, they must redo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that your date/time is correct in BIOS? Also make sure that timedatectl is correct, change timezone if necessary. What ultimately fixed the issue for me was updating /etc/netplan/name-of-file.yaml configuration file with dhcp-identifier: mac.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
  version: 2
```

Comment: there was a problem with lan team, but after that i figured out my system date and time are wrong. after changing date and time, everything works correctly